# Reading from and printing records from a file

Tags: python

I need to be able to read from a file and print records if a variable entered is pre-existent in the file. I have tried to open the file as 'f' however that would only read the first line in the file, heres my code:

```
        problem = input("Please select from one of these: sink, faucet, toilet, shower, heater, other: \n")
        temporaryFile = open("plumberInfo.txt" , "r")
        for row in temporaryFile:
            record = row.split(",")
            if record[6] == problem:
                Pforename = record[1]
                Psurname = record[2]
                Pfee = record[3]
                Pexperience = record[4]
                Prate = record[5]
                print("You have selected", Pforename, Psurname, "they have", Pexperience , "years of experience and they specialise in", problem, "\n")
            else: 
                print("Invalid input")
                plumberSearch() #This part isn't relevant
```

Also below I have attached some contents of the file:

```
743,Auryn,Smith,42.00,6,44.50,faucet,extra
583,Michael,Lanlow,25.00,8,75.00,sink,extra
731,Hanna,Taylor,42.00,14,55.00,heater,extra
981,Tomie,Agen,32.00,6,44.50,toilet,extra
```

I don't understand the problem as it worked fine for when I was searching by the ID ([record0]). There is no traceback error, it just states invalid input which means record[6] != problem, however it is equal.

Comment: You don't show anything about opening the file

Comment: The first few lines of code I posted is opening the file I'm not sure what else is required

Comment: You're right. Your indentation is pretty messed up, so I didn't see it (on mobile). You should fix the indentation, since your code isn't technically valid python otherwise

Comment: It's displaying perfectly fine on my screen, I just pasted it directly from my python shell

Comment: The first line is not indented. The rest is. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: With all due respect that isn't the problem at hand, if it was I would have a typeError, fixed it now.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `if` statement is executed independently for each line of the file. Since the first line doesn't match, it's very important to know what `plumberSearch` does.

Comment: It's just the calling the function which this is all stored in...

Comment: You're posting code that can't be copy and pasted into an editor and run directly. If you were as qualified to assess what's relevant as you think you are, you wouldn't be on this site asking for help. I'm not asking you for completely arbitrary changes.

Comment: Wait, you're making a recursive call? You do realize that you will have to post a proper MCVE or run a debugger yourself to answer that. Any advice you get here will be pure guesswork based on what you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try the code on my machine, printing `record` shows me that the last item contains a new line character at the end. Thus when you search for sink, you're essentially doing the search `sink == sink\n`, hence why you get invalid input.

Reading in the file also reads in the new line, and you need to be aware. You would need to remove it before doing the comparison.

Comment: I added an extra record to the lines just saying "extra" so record[6] wouldn't end in \n however it still didn't work, also I removed the read mode per your instruction and it only reads the first line now?

Comment: I apologize I was unclear, by remove I meant that you would have to remove the newline character, not the read command.

Comment: If I added a 7th record value "extra" would I still need to remove the newline character since record[6] isn't ending on it anymore

Comment: In that case, no. I gave it a try on my machine with "extra" as the last value, and it seemed to work.